# Rails sum two values multiplied together

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `expenses` that have columns: `:quantity` and `unitcost`.  The total expense amount is `:quantity * unit cost`.

`woassets` `have_many :expenses`.

I want to show the total for each `asset` in the `asset` index list.

This works:

```
    <% expensetotal = 0 %>
    <% woasset.expenses.each do |expense| %>
        <% expensetotal = expensetotal + (expense.quantity.to_i * expense.unitcost) %>
    <% end %>
    <td><%= expensetotal %></td>
```

But, is there a better way?

I tried defining `expense total` in the `expense` model, like this:

```
def expense_amount
"#{self.quantity} #{self.unit_price}"
end
```

Then this in the index:

```
<%= woasset.expenses.sum(:expense_amount)
```

But, that didn't work.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What would it mean to sum a string containing two numbers? In any case, why not fill in the expense's total amount on creation/update/save/whatever?

Comment: You can probably also do this directly in the database using aggregate functions. You should explore that, because in general it's faster to let the DB do work and then return the answer, vs getting the data and then doing the work on the server.

Comment: Those are both good alternatives - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
 <td><%= woasset.expenses.map{|e| e.quantity * e.unitcost}.reduce(:+) %></td>
```

Of course, it's better to extract this to a model

```
class Woasset
  def total_expense
    expenses.map{|e| e.quantity * e.unitcost}.reduce(:+)
  end
end

<%= woasset.total_expense %>
```